# query for certain age BY Date of birth in mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I created a database of employees and contains the date of birth with varchar format (31-12-2016) or d-m-Y.
I want to find employees with ages 58 and above. I use this query :

```
$age=mysql_db_query($db,"select * from employees where round(datediff(str_to_date(birth_day,'%d-%m-%Y'), curent_date())/365) > 58",@$koneksi);
$birth = mysql_num_rows($birth);
```

with the above query does not display anything.
what is wrong with the query ??

thanks in advance . . .

Comment: This code displays nothing. Show more.

Comment: Also your curent_date() should be current_date().

Comment: pass`mysql_query` result into `mysql_num_rows`  it would be `$birth = mysql_num_rows($age);`

Comment: `contains the date of birth with varchar format (31-12-2016)` fix that, then get back to us

Comment: Thanks
problem solved bro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `abs()` will give absolute value of a number. Your query returns negative values so you were not getting correct records.

Try to use below query :

```
select * 
from employees 
where abs(round(datediff(str_to_date(birth_day,'%d-%m-%Y'), current_date())/365)) > 58"
```

Also you had used `curent_date` inplace of `current_date()`

Comment: I love it . . . :)

hmmmmm . . . I have one more question, what I have to create a new one. . . or here :)

Comment: Is it related to above question @DammahSifLa?

Comment: you can ask another question as this is marked as answered ;) @DammahSifLa